# splash_scrren not get pushed to login page

Tags: flutter, dart

i have included the Timer but my splash screen not get pushed to login screen. i have used .pushreplacement method to push the splash screen to home .i have done many things but i still get same issue that splash screen not get push to Mylogin(Class).

My main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loginuicolors/home.dart';
import 'package:loginuicolors/login.dart';
import 'package:loginuicolors/register.dart';
import 'package:loginuicolors/splash_screen.dart';
import 'splash_screen.dart';
void main()  {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Splash_screen(),
    routes: {
      'register': (context) => MyRegister(),
      'login': (context) => MyLogin(),
    },
  ));
}
```

Splash_screen.dart file

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'login.dart';

class Splash_screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash_screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Splash_screen> createState() => _Splash_screenState();
}

class _Splash_screenState extends State<Splash_screen> {
  void initstate() {
    super.initState();

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MyLogin(),
          ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/splash_screen.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Splash_screen`, you are calling the `initState` incorrectly.
The code provided contains `initstate` instead of `initState`.

Flutter requires the use of specific method names like `initState` for lifecycle methods to work properly.

These kinds of issues can be annoying and can be avoided by using linting practices, such packages are [flutter_lints](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints) , [very_good_analysis](https://pub.dev/packages/very_good_analysis) and you can find more linters by doing a quick search.

Comment: If this fixed your issue, consider marking my answer as Accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is due the spelling mistake `initState` is the right one.
`initstate` is being treated as a normal function which can be called any time.